# Shopify - how to select all products in a specific collection?

Tags: shopify

I´m new to Shopify and I´m trying to get all the product images that I have added to a collection that I made and called "my catalog".

I have started with this, and it is looping through all the images, but how do I select only the ones with the collection "mycatalog"?

```
{% for product in collection.products %}

<div>
    <a href="{{ url }}">
      <div style="background-image: url('{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}');"> </div>
</a>
</div>

  {% endfor %}
```

I have tested with some different things, but I can´t get it working!

An example would help a lot to understand how it works.
Any input appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for product in collections.mycatalog.products %}

<div>
  <a href="{{ url }}">
    <div style="background-image: url('{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}');"> </div>
  </a>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

See the [Global variables](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/global) page on the Shopify wiki for more info:

> ```
> {% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
>    {{ product.title }} 
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> The liquid variable "collections" contains a list of all of the
>   collections in a shop.

Comment: Not sure if this is a new update to Shopify, but it is worth noting that currently this code does not work. Here in this example it the collection is named My Catalog, and in the code is entered in as mycatalog - which outputs nothing. In the code if you change it to my-catalog it then outputs. Thought it would be helpful to note for anyone like me finding this solution a few years after posting.